# What can I use instead of $product->variation_id in WooCommerce 3?

Tags: woocommerce

I'm upgrading WC version to 3.2.1. I believe everyone who had done woocommerce to 3+ faced this issue.

How can I resolve this problem?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Where Developers Learn, Share, & Build Careers! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Use the "edit" link to improve your question - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

WC > 3.0 now utilizes the `$product->get_id()` method to get the variation ID.

Comment: Yes, that was it! Thanks for your help!